# Move text-cursor of QsciScintilla to the left or right in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, cursor-position, qscintilla

I was wondering what specific commands I can execute to move a text cursor in QsciScintilla to the left or right? I know for a QPlainTextEdit, you can execute the commands:

```
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Left)
```

or:

```
self.textEdit.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Right)
```

Are there any similar commands for QsciScintilla?

I tried:

```
# left cursor movement
line, index = self.sci.getCursorPosition()
if index == 0 and line != 0:
   #move to back line
elif index != 0: 
   self.sci.setCursorPosition(line, index - 1)
```

Comment: [QScintilla Documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciScintilla.html).

Comment: I already checked it out and tried to come up with the code for setCursorPosition but did not succeed

Comment: Then edit your question and add the code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways to do this:

1. Using the [low-level api](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciScintillaBase.html#pub-methods) to send [keyboard commands](https://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#KeyboardCommands) directly to the underlying scintilla editor:

   - Move Left

     ```
       self.sci.SendScintilla(Qsci.QsciScintillaBase.SCI_CHARLEFT)
     ```
   - Move Right

     ```
       self.sci.SendScintilla(Qsci.QsciScintillaBase.SCI_CHARRIGHT)
     ```
2. Using the [high-level api](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/QScintilla/classQsciScintilla.html#aea97c6fb0079a6e3e647443b6101ae9d) to set the line and index explictly:

   - Move Left

     ```
       line, index = self.sci.getCursorPosition()
       if index:
           self.sci.setCursorPosition(line, index - 1)
       elif line:
           self.sci.setCursorPosition(
               line - 1, self.sci.lineLength(line - 1) - 1)
     ```
   - Move Right

     ```
       line, index = self.sci.getCursorPosition()
       if index < self.sci.lineLength(line):
           self.sci.setCursorPosition(line, index + 1)
       elif line < self.sci.lines():
           self.sci.setCursorPosition(line + 1, 0)
     ```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you.